# android: get the application name from inside a module

Tags: android, module

i'm writing an android module, which i will include in some of my projects. Now i need to get the application name(at runtime), e.g. the name that is set as `android:label` for the application in the manifest. Obviously i can't use `getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)` because i can't access the resources of the project that uses this library. Is there another way?
I tried `getApplicationInfo().name` but that is `null` and i can't find anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried getApplicationInfo().name but that is null

That is because `name` comes from the `android:name` attribute on `<application>`, and you are not using a custom `Application` subclass in your app.

> i can't find anything else.

[Call `loadLabel()` on the `ApplicationInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#loadLabel(android.content.pm.PackageManager)), passing in a `PackageManager` as a parameter, to retrieve the `android:label` value for an `<application>` or any component (e.g., `<activity>`).

Comment: thank you, `getApplicationInfo().loadLabel(getPackageManager())` does exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

The module is included in the application so I guess you are calling one of its methods in the application. If it is the case, I propose that you add a parameter in this method to get the context of the application. Then you can use context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) in your module to get the application name.